# Files Larger Than 4GB Are Not Transferring To Hard Drive?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs

Moving things from my laptop to a 1TB hard drive. Stops at any file larger than 4GB saying that that there isn't enough space on the hard drive.

I checked the formatting on my hard drive and it is NTFS.
I thought this was only a problem with FAT32 drives?

I'm running Windows 7 x64

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you attempt to do it.

Comment: Have I missed something lol... when the OP attempts to do it... "Stops at any file larger than 4GB saying that that there isn't enough space on the hard drive"... :S

Comment: Is it possible that this is a limitation of the external harddisk controller ?

Comment: How are you copying the file across? If you try to copy using XCOPY or the more modern ROBOCOPY does it work (may be useful as a work around)

Comment: It used to be that you could format an NTFS drive such that it had a 4GB limit, but I can't see how you could do it now.  Do you have any other external drives attached at the same time?

Comment: Stab in the dark: Your 1TB hard drive is somewhat full already. You have NTFS compression enabled on either the source file/folder or destination drive/folder. Under these conditions a large file may fail to copy. Clue 1: http://tinyurl.com/mv9wqgu
. Clue 2: http://tinyurl.com/lk8ct93. More info: http://tinyurl.com/jvldpeb

Comment: are you still there? post more real information so that it may help others in the future

Comment: `I checked the formatting on my hard drive and it is NTFS` most likely you right click the drive and select Format and then you see NTFS in the file system. That's not correct because that's just the file system you'll format the drive into, not the current format. I've seen many people making the same mistake

Answer (score 1):

Firstly I'm going to second what **vembutech** advises. I have seen a couple of situations where formatting *once more* solved issues not unlike yours. If that doesn't work:

- Are you using 3rd party software to move files? For example, *Explorer++*, *Cubic Explorer*, *MultiCommander*?  If so, try moving the files using Microsoft's built in Windows Explorer.
- It is also possible that the *real-time scanning* feature of your antivirus or antimalware software trips over when a move-in-progress gets past the 4GB mark. Try temporarily disabling all real-time scanning/services and try move the files again.

The 4GB limit is something I have to deal with all the time in my own coding projects (it actually takes a fair bit of understanding and care) and I wouldn't be surprised if some commercial software is not up to par in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

From the information you have posted I suspect that the drive might not formatted properly. To check the file system of the volume, open command prompt run the command `open Diskpart`and then run `list volume`, this command will show you the files system of the volume. If the volume is NTFS try to format the drive once again and try to copy the files.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to format hard disk just for one file. Use `winrar` to break file into small parts and copy them into hard disk. When you want to use this file just extract the first one and your file will be easly transfer.